# Adding 3party Reference To Project with Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I can add reference to project by writing a statement like below.

```
(Get-Project "Test.Project").Object.References.Add("System.Web.Mvc")
```

But how do I add a dll that is in a folder on my computer. The dll that I want to add is not free so there is no package on nuget. So I want to add it to the project by showing its file path ?

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Not via NuGet. NuGet is a package manager. If there is no package, there is nothing NuGet can manage...

Comment: Yes. And i want to add this dll by writing a statement to the package manager console on VS. Its the way I want but I couldnt find any example to the that

Comment: For what it's worth, I have managed this before by using a private nuget server (internal to our LAN), and building packages for the private components.  The nice thing about doing it this way is that you get all the benefits of nuget, and you still keep the component private.  It's particularly nice when you consider automatic package restore -- most of our projects could be pulled from source control onto a fresh developer machine and would "just build" by relying upon package restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. Just giving a full path dll is also ok.

```
(Get-Project).Object.References.Add("C:\ApplicationBase.Core.dll")
```

Comment: I don't see `Get-Project` as a valid cmdlet, do I need a certain package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Add-Type` cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -Path "path-to-dll.dll"
```

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx